# Trouble Saving Nullable Guid to Database EFCore MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework-core, null, guid

I have a property in the entity model
public Guid? TestId { get; set; }
When saving an object with a null TestId to the database, it does not save as null, it comes up in the database as an Empty Guid with value
`00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`. The database column type is `binary(16). Is there a way to make it save as null?

Comment: then that is the default value, you set

Comment: Can you show the code of your Entity class and the Migration generated code for that column?

Comment: No. If the column in the schema is binary(16), then you cannot set it to null. EFCore doesn't even let me set a Guid column as nullable.

Comment: You could possibly change the SQL column data type to `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`, allowing NULL values, and then configure your migration to pass a `DbNull.Value` whenever your `Nullable<Guid>.HasValue == false`. Would that do what you want?